# Opinion about one word

Tags: r

I am analysing some amazon reviews about a pair of headphones. I have found the most frequent words with a `DocumentTermMatrix`, and there are a few interesting ones. In particular, "quality" seems to appear quite often. Is there a way, having a `VCorpus`, to find the words that appear more often with this word? I think it would be appropriate to see if "good" is near "quality" more often than "bad", as an example. I can work either on the corpus or on the original data.frame.
Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look at **bigrams** - pairs of words.

[This chapter](https://www.tidytextmining.com/ngrams.html) of *Text Mining with R* walks through the process of finding and counting n-grams (pairs, or triples, etc.) in R.